# Validation of viewstate with GetCompiledPageInstance

Tags: c#, asp.net

on Default.aspx I wrote this code it succesfully shows me Webform1.aspx but it has also one button when I click on that button it give me error

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pageView = PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance("~/WebForm1.aspx", Server.MapPath("~/WebForm1.aspx"), HttpContext.Current);
        (pageView).ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);

    }
```

**Error on button click**

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
```

Comment: Can you update your question and tell us more about your webconfig in this regard as well as the full @Page directive in your both ASPX files? Its a must to know in order to find a definite solution for you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try these:

define the following parameter in your both page directives after @ Page in your .aspx files.

EnableViewState="false

Then add this in your webcofig in the system.web tag:

and modify your pages tag if exists or add as follows:

I do think it will serve your purpose.

PS: I am using all above in my own project in which I am creating instances of many webusercontrols in side my application and it works fine!

Comment: hmm very strange, can you update your question and tell us more about your webconfig in this regard as well as the full @Page directive in your both ASPX files? Its a must to know in order to find a definite solution for you.